# How to create a CSS identifier from an arbitrary string with python?

Tags: python, regex, django

Working on a Django Template tag, I find myself needing to take a string and convert it into a CSS identifier so it can be part of a class attribute on an html element.  The problem is the string can contain spaces which makes it useless as a CSS identifier, and it could contain punctuation as well.

My thoughts were to use a regex to rip out the good parts and then put them back together, but I can't figure out how to express the repeating group pattern.  Here is what I have

```
to_css = re.compile(r"[^a-z_-]*([a-z0-9_-]+[^a-z0-9_]*)+", re.IGNORECASE)
@register.filter(name='as_css_class')
def as_css_class(value):
    matches = to_css.match(value)
    if matches:
        return '-'.join(matches.groups())
    return ""
```

The problem comes with you do this:

```
as_css_class("Something with a space in it")
```

and you get

```
'it'
```

I was hoping the + would apply to the (group), but evidently it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Python cannot match the same group multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) for this:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
slugify("Something with a space in it")
```

Comment: This one had the benefit of not requiring any code from me, only has that problem with leading digits and leading hyphen followed by a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will match the whole string and the only group catched will be "it" (therefore the result). A capturing group will only keep the last string it captured. You can't catch an arbitrary number of strings with one regex.

What you can do however, is use the global modifier `g` (or simply `re.findall` in Python I believe). Something like:

```
re.findall(r'[\w-]+');
```

and then join the result (more or less, my Python's a little rusted).

Answer (score -1):

Does it need to be a CSS class?

```
<div data-something="Anything you like provided it's HTML escaped"> ... </div>
```

```css
div[data-something="Anything you like provided it's HTML escaped"] {
    background: red;
}
```

Arguably you shouldn't be shoe-horning arbitrary data into the class, since you risk clashing with an existing class. Data attributes allow you to specify information with name clashes.

Comment: Yes, its going in a class="string-here"